# Should I ask why I didn't get a response for 6 months?

Tags: email, freelancing

About half a year ago I got an e-mail regarding possible freelance work. Unfortunately this message ended up in my spam folder which I rarely ever check.

It was about 2 weeks later that I found it and replied back. I did apologize and was honest that it went straight through my spam, and told him if he's still keen that I'd be excited to get more details about the role.

I got absolutely no reply back and figured it was a lost cause. Fast forward to yesterday, I get a message from him where he asks me if I'm interested. And interesting enough, he also mentions they "lost touch" with the last guy they were in contact and working with.

Now that was a 6 months hiatus so a part of me wants to ask what happened there? I also find it rude that he didn't even bother to reply that they're no longer interested.

What are your guys thoughts on this? Should I just let it go and forget about it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why would you care? They were probably busy at the time, had already filled the requirement and just put your name aside in-case they needed you in future... Which it sounds like they do.

Comment: Agreed. Potential client's work days don't revolve around keeping in touch with freelancers they may or may not ever contract with. Be glad that they reached out. If they use your services, great. If they don't, no hard feelings. Have a nice life.

Comment: I just find it unprofessional to not send a quick chaser, but I do agree with you both, thanks guys.

Comment: The way you describe it, you worded it as a "If there is still interest from your side, get in touch with me." Presumably, there was no interest at the time, so they probably thought "Well, there is no interest, and it would be a waste of both ours and the guy's time to send a message about that."